# jal instruction in MIPS assembly language does'nt save return address

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

This is my code:

```
.globl main

.data

.text

Read_Input: 
    
    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    jr $ra

        
main:

    
    jal Read_Input
    move $t1, $v0
    
    jal Read_Input
    move $t2, $v0
    
    jal Read_Input
    move $t3, $v0
    
    nop
    
END:

    li  $v0, 10
    syscall
```

I get an error, Error in : invalid program counter value: 0x00000000 which means that my jal did not succed in storing the return address. Am I doing anything wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you need to single step this (from the very beginning), and hopefully you'll realize what is going wrong here.

Comment: Note that MARS will start executing at the beginning of the `.text` section (i.e. `Read_Input`) unless you've selected `Initialize program counter to global 'main' if defined` in the settings.

Comment: @ErikEidt When I am stepping it, jal does not add any address from what I can see in the register for $ra before the jump. Then after I have entered an integer the program crashes because there are no return address. I cant seem to find the problem. From what I have read, it can be that way. But of course I am doing something wrong, otherwise it would work.

Comment: @Michael I am not sure. I will check that. Thank you.

Comment: @Michael Yeah it was unchecked. That solved it. Thanks again.

Comment: When single stepping, didn't notice that the first instruction it runs is the `li` in `Read_Input`, not a `jal` in `main`?

Comment: Btw, many put the `main` first rather than checking the option.